# How to copy a complete ziped folder to target using ftp in python?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have to copy a ziped folder using ftplib as follows:

```
 ftp = FTP('ip')
 ftp.login(user='user', passwd = 'pass')
 filename=  "D:/sample.zip"
 ftp.storlines("STOR " + os.path.basename(filename), open(filename,"r"))
```

On the remote the sample folder does gets copied but it is just '1kb' size in actual its size is 2963Kb. So, could you help me out how shall i copy the complete ziped folder on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use [`storbinary()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) and not `storlines`. The latter is for ASCII files.

And since zip files are binary, the file should be opened in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + os.path.basename(filename), open(filename, "rb"))
```